# Emberjs custom config variables

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, configuration

How would one specify a custom config variable for use in the handlebars template?

For example:

```
// config/settings.json

{
  "title": "Hello World"
}

// config/foo.json
{
  "bar": "baz"
}

// Template

{{ settings.title }}
{{ foo.bar }}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use dependency injection to inject you global variables into the controller. [This blog post](http://balinterdi.com/2014/05/01/dependency-injection-in-ember-dot-js.html) from Balint Erdi explains it well.
[Here is a working demo.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cogil/1/edit)
This is basically what you do

- Create 2 object - settings and foo.

  ```
  var settings = Ember.Object.extend({
    title: 'Hello World'
  });

  var foo = Ember.Object.extend({
    bar: 'baz'
  });
  ```
- Register these 2 objects in the container using an application initializer.

  ```
  container.register('globals:settings', settings, { singleton: true });
  container.register('globals:foo', foo, { singleton: true });
  ```
- Inject the 2 registered object into all the controllers.

  ```
  application.inject('controller', 'settings', 'globals:settings');
  application.inject('controller', 'foo', 'globals:foo');
  ```

Here's is the complete code for the above 2 steps in an initializer

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: "globals",

  initialize: function(container, application) {
    container.register('globals:settings', settings, { singleton: true });
    container.register('globals:foo', foo, { singleton: true });

    application.inject('controller', 'settings', 'globals:settings');
    application.inject('controller', 'foo', 'globals:foo');
  }
});
```

You can then reference the values in your template as

```
{{settings.title}}
```