# Importing custom config files in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have created a custom config file and I am importing it to be used in the App Initializer as per my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23802629/emberjs-custom-config-variables).

The problem is that when I `console.log` the imported variable I get `unknown mixin`.

Config File:

```
export default Ember.Object.extend({
    "title": "Foo Bar"
});
```

Initializer:

```
import settings from 'appkit/config/settings';

// code removed for brevity

console.log(settings);
```

Comment: Are you using EAK? If so, this might answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/23729225/548568

Comment: Yeah I am using EAK. Thanks for the help, that answer helped solve it.